# Clear $scope on logout in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller I am storing data as `$scope.$parent.dossierSummaries = data;`
but after log out and login the application `$scope.$parent.dossierSummaries` retains the same old data.

I am doing this on log out

```
.success( function( response, status ) {
    if ( response.status > 0 ) {
        var u = $rootScope.user.username;
        $cookieStore.remove('myapp');
        $rootScope.user = { username: '', role: 0 };
        success(u);
    }
    else {
        error(response.messages);
    }
})
.error( function( response, status ) {
    error(['There was an error logging you out.']);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any effective way to achieve it. Any object (controller, directive,filter or as a matter of fact any js object) can hold reference to another object (in your case user), and one cannot determine easily who all are holding reference.

The reference would only get release if you do it either explicitly or when the object holder the reference is destroyed.

What you can try is

```
$rootScope.user.username='';
$rootScope.role=0;
```

Assuming some object are tracking this specific object the data would be cleared now.

Answer (score 3):

in angularJS, you shouldn't set the variable directly to a controller but you should retrieve it from a service instead. So whenever you load a controller you should write a `init()` function to get value of that model. So everytime you will have the correct data from server.

Code example and docs : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services

Comment: What would be a good approach for clearing data which is stored in services?

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to manually tracking and cleaning things up would be to `broadcast` a 'logout' event on the `rootScope` (or other custom event). Then listen for the event either in your controller or in your service to clean up the data.

Broadcast:

```
$rootScope.broadcast('logout');
```

Watching for an event (in a service for example):

```
$rootScope.on('logout',function(){
  dossiers = [];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

if you don't mind a slight screen flickering on logout, you can refresh the page using a method like this:

```
$window.location.replace($window.location.toString().split('#')[0]);
```

this would clear out all the `$scope` and `$rootScope` variables, and in my case has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the $scope, I think you can use it's constructor method or **proto** (prototype), which is used in constructor. I believe you can do that to reset the scope to initial state. If someone knows any more on this, feel free to comment.