# How to clear session storage using service

Tags: angularjs, sessionstorage, clear-cache

In angularjs , i have a logout button. To clear the session storage im using window.sessionStorage.clear(). But I want to clear session storage using service. The service im using is LocalCacheService .How to clear sessionStorage using this service

```
'controller': ["$scope","LocalCacheService", function ($scope,LocalCacheService) {
console.log("Logout Controller called....");
$scope.Logout = {
}
}]
```

In that logout what should i add to clear session storage using service

Comment: have you follow any example code for logout with service ?

Comment: No i want some example to clear session storage using service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26523823/3514144

Answer (score 1):

You are able to clear all data stored within sessionStorage if required.

In order to clear everything stored by your application within sessionStorage you should use the following:

```
$sessionStorage.empty();
```

See the link http://ghost.scriptwerx.io/angularjs-sessionstorage/

Answer (score 0):

Set Window session key with NULL in logout service.. as below.

```
 $window.sessionStorage["windowKey"] = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the regular injection rule in angularjs.

app.service('service1', function(){});

//Inject service1 into service2

app.service('service2',function(service1){});

It is better to use Array injection to avoid minifying problem.

app.service('service2',['service1', function(service1) {}]);

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$sessionStorage.$reset()`

Worked for me.