# How can I clear all the AngularJS $scope and $rootScope values within a single function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I need to clear all the **`$scope`** values while performing some operations.

For eg: If I Click a **`"Signout"`** button to redirect to **`"signin"`** page, then all the **$scope** or **$rootScope** values in the session should be cleared.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Here you can find some methods to achieve that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085024/reset-a-model-with-angular-js

Comment: @frhd. Thanks its clear. Using this example we can clear $scope values in the particular controller. But I want to clear all the $scope values in all the controllers during signout. Is it possible? If yes, give me you suggestion/solution..

Comment: I don't think there is a one-liner-kind-of way to clear all the scopes. As written here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18527334/2491198, you would need to notify all scopes to delete their data. One way to avoid having to do that, is storing the data in a **DataService** and clearing that on logout.

Comment: I dont know if you have heard of Ionic Framework. But they do have a similar function where you just call the ` $ionicHistory.clearCache();
          $ionicHistory.clearHistory(); ` Maybe read the source code for this?

Answer (score 16):

You can do the following:

```
$rootScope = $rootScope.$new(true);
$scope = $scope.$new(true);
```

The function `$new` is creating a new scope inheriting the variables from the parent. `true` prevents the inheritance.

But this is not the correct approach, because if you use the thing above, you should bootstrap the controllers functions manually and recreating the tree of scopes.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085024/reset-a-model-with-angular-js) might be useful though, where the idea is to store the initialized data is stored in some variables and then, when assigned copied to the displayed variables.

The correct solution is to clear manually every property in each scope on the logout event like this:
Logout event:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("logout");
```

Catching the event:

```
$rootScope.$on("logout", function(){
      $rootScope.myData = undefined;
});
```

Or as suggested in the comments, to use a service and then be cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

```
               You not want delete scope 
               var authScope =['authLogo','currentPath','pageTitle','app'];                       
                for (var prop in $rootScope) {
                    if (prop.substring(0,1) !== '$') {
                        if(authScope.indexOf(prop) ==-1)
                            delete $rootScope[prop];
                    }
                }
```