# How to clear $rootScope completely when my application gets signout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive

I used $rootScope and $scope inside many controllers and services.I have reffered many stack overflow answer for clearing all $scope and $rootScope values solution.But it doesnt work for me(solutions like $rootScope=undefined or $rootScope=''). Kindly help me out of it.[image: My Logout Code]

Comment: Please insert code into the question as text, not as an image.  You should also include any error messages as text, as well, because "it doesn't work" is not a good description of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should delete your properties from `$roorScope`. It should be:

```
delete $rootScope.yourProperty1;
delete $rootScope.yourProperty2;
```

If have many properties, you should use:

```
for (var prop in $rootScope) {

   // Check is not $rootScope default properties, functions
   if (typeof $rootScope[prop] !== 'function' && prop.indexOf('$') == -1 && prop.indexOf('$$') == -1) {

      delete $rootScope[prop];

   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i have 100+ properties. It works if i delete my individual property like you answered. Am asking if there is any other way for clearing all $rootScope and $Scope instead clearing individual property using delete

Comment: See my updated answer, I think you should delete your properties with for loop :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
$rootScope.$on("logout", function(){
  $rootScope.userRole= undefined;});
```

Comment: I have cleared the whole cache and tried dude.. It doesnt makes sense

Comment: ok try this code.$rootScope.$on("logout", function(){
  $rootScope.userRole= undefined;});

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to clear all the defined properties on $rootScope and want to retain the initial values that come with $rootScope, you can do this by deleting all the properties on $rootScope that do not start with $. As all the initial properties are defined with $.

```
$rootScope.$clearScope = function() {
    for (var prop in $rootScope) {
        if (prop.substring(0,1) !== '$') {
            delete $rootScope[prop];
        }
    }
}
```

Also, have a look to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817252/how-can-i-clear-all-the-angularjs-scope-and-rootscope-values-within-a-single-f).